# How to get data from specific position from IEnumerable<> object?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I want to get element from `IEnumerable` from specific position without using `forloop`.

I have to get element from `IEnumerable` by Varible called:

```
int position;


public class Employee
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public int Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}


int position=2;
IEnumerable<Employee> data = (from c in context.Employee select c);
data = data.ElementAtOrDefault(position);
```

**Error on above line:Cannot implicitly convert type Employee to System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable.**

But i want to get data from specific position in `data variable` only because rest all my code address this variable `data`.

**Note**:If value of my position varible is greater than 0 then i will find data from data variable with this position but if position variable = 0 then i will return Ienumerable.

How to do this???

Comment: Why are you declaring data as IEnumerable, if you are expecting a single object then u could declare it as an Employee object.

Comment: Indeed: `Employee employee = data.ElementAtOrDefault(position);`

Comment: @wintersolider:Actually whether i want to get a single object or list ob object that depends upon my position variable.If position value is 0 then i will return list if position is greater than zero then i will return specific element from data variable using position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very easily using `Linq`

For example if you need to get item at position 2 simply use -

```
data = data.Skip(1).Take(1);
```

Or as per your query -

```
data = data.Skip(position - 1).Take(1);
```

Comment: Here where my position varibale would come in your solution?

Comment: @Learning - The Skip extension method internally allocates a new class that is compiler-generated and stores the state of the Skip operation. This indicates that using a for-loop and starting at the desired index will be much faster

Comment: Is this correct:data = data.Skip(position).Take(position);?

Comment: @Learning - Updated my answer. You just need to skip to one item less then your position, and take next single item.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<Employee> data= null;
IEnumerable<Employee> tempList = (from c in context.Employee select c);
if(position==0)
  data = tempList;
else if(position >0)
{
  data = templist.Skip(position -1).Take(1);
}
```

You are getting the error because you are trying to store a single object into a variable of type IEnumerable.

By combining Yogi's Answer you could do the following.

Comment: Updated my answer using LINQ query specified in Yogi's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
if(position > 0)
   data = GetDataAt(data,position);
```

Where GetDataAt:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetDataAt<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataItems, int position)
{
yield return dataItems.ElementAtOrDefault(position);
}
```